# Threejs load model into scene

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I created a simple model in blender and then exported it to json format, it looks like:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.4,
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
    },
    "geometries": [
        {
            "uuid": "A46CC9F4-2709-41D0-98E7-D07FF9DC2890",
            "type": "BufferGeometry",
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "position": {
                        "itemSize": 3,
                        "type": "Float32Array",
                        "array": [0.686574,-0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686573,-0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686573,0.102986,1.89577,0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,-1.89577,0.686573,0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686573,-0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,1.89577,0.686573,0.102986,1.89577,0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686573,0.102986,1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,0.686573,0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,-0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577,0.686574,-0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686573,-0.102986,-1.89577,-0.686574,0.102986,-1.89577],
                        "normalized": false
                    },
                    "normal": {
                        "itemSize": 3,
                        "type": "Float32Array",
                        "array": [0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,-0.000001,0,1,-0.000001,0,1,-0.000001,0,0,-0.000005,1,0,-0.000005,1,0,-0.000005,1,-1,-0.000001,0,-1,-0.000001,0,-1,-0.000001,0,0.000001,0.000005,-1,0.000001,0.000005,-1,0.000001,0.000005,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0.000002,0,1,0.000002,0,1,0.000002,0,-0.000001,0.000002,1,-0.000001,0.000002,1,-0.000001,0.000002,1,-1,-0.000001,0,-1,-0.000001,0,-1,-0.000001,0,0.000001,0.000003,-1,0.000001,0.000003,-1,0.000001,0.000003,-1],
                        "normalized": false
                    }
                },
                "index": {
                    "type": "Uint16Array",
                    "array": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35]
                },
                "boundingSphere": {
                    "center": [0,0,0],
                    "radius": 2.018894
                }
            }
        }],
    "materials": [
        {
            "uuid": "C34E0E05-B2F6-44B9-B810-D97E70E983E3",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 7722888,
            "depthFunc": 3,
            "depthTest": true,
            "depthWrite": true,
            "skinning": false,
            "morphTargets": false
        }],
    "object": {
        "uuid": "FD99C549-4D01-4176-8003-8994CBE8B321",
        "type": "Mesh",
        "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
        "geometry": "A46CC9F4-2709-41D0-98E7-D07FF9DC2890",
        "material": "C34E0E05-B2F6-44B9-B810-D97E70E983E3"
    }
}
```

Then I followed three.js documentation and want to load my model into scene. Html file is:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>My first three.js app</title>
      <style>
       body { margin: 0; }
       canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
      <script>
       var scene = new THREE.Scene();
       var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
       var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
       renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
       document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
       var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
       loader.load("model(1).json", function ( obj ) {
        scene.add( obj );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
         console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
         console.error( 'An error happened' );
        }
       );
       
       var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
       };
       render();
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to open this in browser(firefox) but someting goes wrong. I have two warnings in console `THREE.WebGLRenderer 84` and `NaN% loaded`(second is from my html file). There is only black screen as my scene and nothing happens. How is it possible to solve my problem and load model as json into scene via three.js?

Comment: It took me some time but I found the problem: the camera is at 0,0,0, which is *inside* the object. Just add `camera.position.z = 5;` and you should see it. Also add `display: block;` to the canvas style rule so you'll get rid of the scroll bars. I get `100% loaded` btw, with the model file in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: Thanks, it works. There is still an error `THREE.WebGLRenderer 84`. Should I ignore it?

Comment: That's not an error.

Comment: that's not an error, it's just showing which version of ThreeJS you're using. It's just a console log, you can ignore it.